# How to simplify this series?

Tags: power-series

I have the series
$$
P_i = 1 = \bigg[1 + \frac{q}{p} + \bigg(\frac{q}{p}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{q}{p}\bigg)^3 + \cdots + \bigg(\frac{q}{p}\bigg)^{i-1}  \bigg]P_1
$$

We have the boundary condition
$$
P_N=1
$$

Apparently, if we assume $p\neq q$, we obtain
$$
P_N = \frac{1-\bigg(\frac{q}{p}\bigg)^N}{1-\bigg(\frac{q}{p}\bigg)}P_1
$$

Could someone explain how the power series was simplified to this?

Comment: Are you familiar with geometric progressions?

Comment: @Gary, somewhat, although I've really only dealt with simplifying basic stuff like $\sum_{i=1}^N (\frac{1}{2})^i$.

Comment: Having $q/p$ in place of $1/2$ does not change much. Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

Comment: @Gary. Thanks I'll look at the resource.

Answer (score 0):

A geometric sum. It is easy to prove (e.g. by induction) that if $a\ne 1$:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a^k
     &= \frac{a^{n + 1} - 1}{a - 1}
\end{align*}$

If $a = 1$, obviously:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a^k
     &= n + 1
\end{align*}$